# Cannot process url with vertical/pipe bar in Java/Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

If I want to process this url for example:

```
post = new HttpPost("http://testurl.com/lists/lprocess?action=LoadList|401814|1");
```

Java/Apache won't let me because it says that the vertical bar ("|") is illegal.

escaping it with double slashes doesn't work as well:

```
post = new HttpPost("http://testurl.com/lists/lprocess?action=LoadList\\|401814\\|1");
```

^ that doesn't work as well.

Any suggestions how to make this work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try with `URLEncoder.encode()`

**Note:** you should encode string which is after `action=` not `complete URL`

```
post = new HttpPost("http://testurl.com/lists/lprocess?action="+URLEncoder.encode("LoadList|401814|1","UTF-8"));
```

Refernce http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: This is correct. Encoding the whole String will fail because URI would not recognize the encoded `http://`.

Answer (score 10):

You must encode `|` in a URL as `%7C`.

Consider using HttpClient's [`URIBuilder`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) which takes care of the escaping for you, e.g.:

```
final URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
builder.setScheme("http")
    .setHost("testurl.com")
    .setPath("/lists/lprocess")
    .addParameter("action", "LoadList|401814|1");
final URI uri = builder.build();
final HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
```

Comment: This answer is more verbose than [the one by Tarsem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18316373/177710) but helps realize what parts there are in a URI. On the other hand, it keeps the handling and encoding nicely hidden in the implementation details of `URIBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and I solve it replacing the | for a encoded value of it => %7C and ir works

From this

```
post = new HttpPost("http://testurl.com/lists/lprocess?action=LoadList|401814|1");
```

To this

```
post = new HttpPost("http://testurl.com/lists/lprocess?action=LoadList\\%7C401814\\%7C1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode URL parameters using the [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

```
post = new HttpPost("http://testurl.com/lists/lprocess?action=" + URLEncoder.encode("LoadList|401814|1", "UTF-8"));
```

This will encode all special characters, not just the pipe, for you.

Answer (score 0):

In post we don't attach parameters to url. Code below adds and urlEncodes your parameter. It's taken from: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://testurl.com/lists/lprocess");

    List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "LoadList|401814|1"));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
    HttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

    try {
        System.out.println(response2.getStatusLine());
        HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
        // do something useful with the response body
        // and ensure it is fully consumed

        String response = new Scanner(entity2.getContent()).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        System.out.println(response);


        EntityUtils.consume(entity2);
    } finally {
        httpPost.releaseConnection();
    }
```

Comment: Quoting: *"In post we don't attach parameters to url."* This is not true. You can very well send data in a POST request using URL parameters and it does not collide with any standards.