# java.net.URISyntaxException when i try to post a URL

Tags: java, apache, url

Hi am sending a url using apache HttpClient by using following code but it has been showing a exception :java.net.URISyntaxException:

```
Illegal character in query at index 70: http://192.155.2.144:8080/SDAX/homePage.do?actionFlag=istrict&&MSG=1|Bdrtfggf|254td|return|null|null|null
```

Please help me where iam doing the problem. the following code i am sending a URL

```
        String MSG="1|Bdrtfggf|254td|return|null|null|null" ; 
        String url="http://192.168.2.144:8080/SDAX/homePage.do?actionFlag=edistrict&&MSG="+MSG;
        System.out.println("Url is"+url);

        //String url = "http://192.168.0.6:8084/NRC_NEW_SEARCH/getVillageList.req?dist_id=1";
        //String url="http://192.168.0.85:8080/poly/web/";
        //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);
        //ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        //context..redirect(url);
        HttpRequestBase request = new HttpGet(url);
        /*HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter("dist_id", "1");
        request.setParams(params);*/
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpClient.execute(request);
```

Comment: Is it edistrict&&MSG ?

Comment: Yes i have removed one & from that

Answer (score 0):

You should `encode` the `MSG` string before creating a `URL` from it.

```
String encodedMSG = URLEncoder.encode(MSG, "UTF-8")
String url="http://192.168.2.144:8080/SDAX/homePage.do?actionFlag=edistrict&&MSG="+ encodedMSG;
```

**Edit**

There won't be any problem in retrieving the data after encoding. If you have programmed this servlet `homePage.do` then you should use `URLDecoder.decode()` method in it.

Comment: if i encode it then is there any problem to get that data from the URL

Comment: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: exception i am getting after encode

Comment: @ASADUL Make sure you are using a valid host/ip/file path?

Comment: @ASADUL its not a valid ip. I tried to `telnet` it but couldn't connect. Please re-check the address,.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since vertical bar(|) is not a valid URI character thats why You are getting URISyntaxException. 
   **Solution:**
   As suggested by kaysush, you need to encode/decode your url.
   For more on this, Please check folowing url:
   [Cannot process url with vertical/pipe bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316242/cannot-process-url-with-vertical-pipe-bar-in-java-apache-httpclient)
2. You havn't explained what you are trying to achieve here. I hope it isn't by mistake. but
   As per you question, You are trying to post a url and In your code you are using HttpGet(url);

Comment: i just want to post the parameter to that url so that we can get parameter form that url